# Cron for restarting a service when it fails on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I have made a service which contains some redis operations and node scripts on a ubuntu Amazon Ec2 instance. However when there are any errors the service stops with a pid.

I need a cron job to do the following :

1. detect when service has failed
2. delete the pid
3. restart the service

I have seen that cron can be created for time interval but have not come across if this can be done for service fail scenarios as well . Any hints and answers on this will be very helpful .

Comment: You want a service to keep running your app written in node.js in case it stops, is that?

Comment: yes . I want the service to restart itself even if there occurs an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever). From their page:

> A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously (i.e. forever).

The usage is quite simple:

```
forever start your_app.js
```

You can read the documentation in their page: [Forever - Github](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever). You have several examples here: [Forever examples](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor/tree/master/examples).

There are other alternatives:

1. Monit: http://mmonit.com/monit/
2. Upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
3. Daemontools: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html
4. Launchtool: http://people.debian.org/~enrico/launchtool.html

Answer (score 1):

Other alternatives I like (which they're not written in Node.js) are:

- [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) (Python)
- [lockrun](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.html) (C - really lightweight)